# Monitoring Stack Exchange sites of interest to me

Tags: feature-request, notifications, subscription

Is there a way to subscribe to relevant updates on this site and Stack Overflow and Server Fault (through RSS or something)? Being interested in 3 forums means 3 times as much work to check them.

---

It's been a while, and features have changed, so I'm wondering if this could be revisited as a feature-request:

[image]

This box is the dropdown box for the Stack Exchange logo in the upper left. It has tabs for hot questions across all sites, a list of all Stack Exchange sites, and responses/comments for questions I've participated in.

Could you folks either replace the "hot questions" tab, or make a new tab, so it's only for the sites I'm a member of? Or better yet, make it a preference so I can select which sites I want to see.

Comment: I don't remember when this got implemented, but it did.

Answer (score 4):

Sorta kinda.  Check out this [Yahoo Pipes example for StackOverflow](http://pipes.yahoo.com/flenser/stackoverflow_merge_tag_feeds) done by [Sam Hasler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2541/sam-hasler).  You can click View Source under the pipe and modify it for your own needs.  In the String Builder box, you can customize it to match just the tags you want to search on, and then clone the pipe.  You can build 3 different pipes - one for each site, each monitoring the tags you want - and then subscribe to the results via an RSS reader or with email alerts.