# Is there a way to get an RSS feed of all new questions?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, questions, feed

I'm only interested in receiving new questions, and receiving each question once (for example, I don't care if it gets answers or comments - I don't want a question showing up in the feed more than once). However, I haven't seen this option, but I could have overlooked it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a "secret" RSS feed, intended for bots which contains all new questions (it's used for `sobot` in the irc.freenode.net #stackoverflow channel), but I don't think it's publicised, so I'm hesitant to link to it.. If you really want it, I guess the best thing is to email the SO team (the "contact us" link in the footer)

There's obviously there is https://stackoverflow.com/feeds - but that's only "popular" questions.

There's a "Planned" Uservoice ticket ["Provide rss for all views  "](https://web.archive.org/web/20090406111122/http://stackoverflow.uservoice.com:80/pages/general/suggestions/24713-provide-rss-for-all-views)

One comment on that ticket mentions you can get a feed of all questions for a specific tag: https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag/scala

Comment: I think I'll email the SO team. This "secret" feed sounds like exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: @Thomas Did you get it?

Answer (score 5):

This is now possible, but **only by tag**.

See the RSS feeds linked on the tag view, for the "newest" tab:

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=feature-request&sort=newest

Answer (score 0):

No, there is not, apart from using the data dump and creating it for yourself, which would be oddly outdated once you get it.

I support the feature.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can, with Yahoo Pipes.  Check out my answer to this related question:

[Monitoring Stack Exchange sites of interest to me](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/224/monitoring-this-site-and-stackoverflow-and-server-fault)