# Syndication feed for the whole Meta site?

Tags: support, status-completed, feed

I do not find in meta.so.com a syndication feed for *all* the questions, only for the tags. Since meta has much less traffic than [StackOverflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/684/is-there-a-way-to-get-an-rss-feed-of-all-new-questions), it would be sensible.

I was able to follow stackoverflow.uservoice this way and I miss this feature. Any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about https://meta.stackoverflow.com/feeds/ ? That looks about right. Admittedly I only found it be experimentation...

Answer (score 0):

Go to the homepage, scroll to the bottom, and look for the RSS icon -- it's there!

Additionally, the homepage and list by tag pages have individual RSS feeds for each tab now.

Comment: Perhaps it would be worth putting on the "Questions" page as well?

Answer (score -1):

The feed for all questions is offered in the URL bar (of a modern browser at least) when you visit the frontpage http://meta.stackoverflow.com.

The URL is indeed h t t p : / / m e t a . s t a c k o v e r f l o w . c o m / f e e d s/.

This is what I'd expect, but of course it would not hurt to advertise this feature more prominently.

Comment: I was talking about meta.stackoverflow.com, not www.stackoverflow.com. With Firefox, I see no syndication link for meta.

Comment: Me too:-). Just a typo in the first link, fixed that, the second one was OK. Anyway, syndication for the whole page I'd expect at the front page. Thats how it is at meta, so and sf.