# Best way to browse SO with minimum effort for new questions

Tags: feature-request, homepage, ease-of-use

I was wondering if SO can have a Twitter style of new question notification on the page so that one knows how many new questions have come up and also if it is possible to filter this page with only the tags you want. Somewhat like Twitter search.

Also, something like Friendfeed could work too, which automatic scrolling.

I see that refreshing the page does not always work for me and I miss some questions. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not down voting because I hate the idea. I'm down voting because Jeff would never go for it. Although, we really do need a better way to be notified of new questions.

Comment: +1, Make sure and upvote this question to at least get a tab that does filtering on your interesting tags, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11563/tab-for-interesting-questions

Comment: Upvoted that question.

Answer (score 5):

The site has an rss feed for new questions. It also has a feature for identifying tags you like/dislike. Plus, there's an api in the works if you'd like to develop some little tools for yourself, as so many others have been doing or plan on doing.

- [Is there any way to get an RSS feed of all new questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/684/is-there-a-way-to-get-an-rss-feed-of-all-new-questions)
- [Trilogy Addicts  Get "real-time" notifications of new questions.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44545/trilogy-addicts-get-real-time-notifications-of-new-questions)

Comment: Up voting requires at lest 15 reputation. You just missed an up vote from me. I am at 11 right now. :)

Thanks for your answer though.