# Is there an RSS feed for *all new* questions?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, feed

Based on the fact that the solution for an [older question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/684/is-there-a-way-to-get-an-rss-feed-of-all-new-questions) [only works for tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/696/130301), are there plans to create feeds for new questions of entire SO sites? For me it would be nicer to have unedited titles and contents than seeing the same questions over and over again.

`http://unix.stackexchange.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=*&sort=newest` didn't work.

Comment: We already have `/feeds` which is the active question list (ordered by last activity date, which defaults to creation)...do you mean a newest *only* feed, strictly sorted by creation and not accounting for activity?

Comment: Each question should appear once and only once.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is odd we don't mirror this specific sort globally where we do the other question sorts...but easy enough to remedy.  In the next build there will be a `/feeds/newest` which is based *only* on CreationDate of a post, not LastActivityDate like the current `/feeds` route.

Comment: You are a status-completed ***machine*** today.

Comment: Just verified http://security.stackexchange.com/feeds/newest - Thank you!