# How can I subscribe to an RSS feed of all questions, regardless of tags?

Tags: support, questions, feed

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to get an RSS feed of all new questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/684/is-there-a-way-to-get-an-rss-feed-of-all-new-questions)
>   [Is there an RSS feed for *all new* questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116731/is-there-an-rss-feed-for-all-new-questions)

I know I can subscribe to certain tags to grab the question list, but I was wondering if there is a way to get an RSS that contains *all* of the questions, regardless of their tags.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to get an RSS feed of all new questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/684/is-there-a-way-to-get-an-rss-feed-of-all-new-questions), [Is there an RSS feed for *all new* questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116731/is-there-an-rss-feed-for-all-new-questions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/